# How to click on an element in hidden iframe using Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I want to find elements inside an *iframe* tag. However, in the HTML source there isn't any *iframe* tag. If I inspect element there is, though. How to solve this using Selenium library in Python 2.7?

#### HTML source

[Screenshot](http://prnt.sc/d61dxn)

Inspect element

[Screenshot](http://prnt.sc/d61b6c)

Comment: Did you use webdriver.switchTo().frame("card-field...") before using find elements under that frame?

Comment: @Moshisho I can't do that because selenium uses HTML source code not Code from inspect element. In the source code the iframe is not even mentioned. Idk how to solve this :(

Comment: Did you get this source code using Selenium getPageSource()? Can you add your code to the question? And do you have an example URL?

Answer (score 0):

If it's dynamically generated, it could explain why it's not found in the Selenium version of the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). You can still get it by using JavaScript in your code.

```
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('card-fields-iframe')")
```

Comment: When you say dynamically generated, do you mean the usage of JavaScript? As in DHTML https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_HTML?wprov=sfsi1 ? Or maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: yes. via pre written javascript or some response from the server via AJAX

Comment: if the generated HTML has been inserted to the page (and not in the memory waiting for some action) which is usually the case, selenium can access that element since it has always the latest DOM i.e. what the user sees and has access to (via inpection for example).